# Proving that L(V) cannot be finite dimensional given an identity.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let V be a vector space over K, $CharK=0$. Let $S,T\in L(V)$ such that $ST-TS=I$.
> Prove that $$S^{n+1}T-TS^{n+1}=(n+1)S^n\tag1$$ for every $n=0,1,2,3...$.
> Use this identity to establish that in this case L(V) is an infinite dimensional vector space.

I am able to prove the relation
$S^{n+1}T-TS^{n+1}=(n+1)S^n$ using mathematical induction, but in the later I'm having problem.

I know I have to suppose that the dimension is finite say n and then show that there exists a linearly independent set in L(V) with cardinality greater that n.

I have this gut feeling that the set
$\{I,S,S²,...,Sⁿ\}$ is linearly independent for any n which will prove that there cannot be any finite linearly independent set to act as the basis of L(V). But in the process of proving that I faced problem

Suppose, we have scalars $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...\alpha_n$ from the field such that
$$\alpha_0I+\alpha_1S+...\alpha_nS^n=0\tag2$$
Using the identity (1) we have obtained
$$\implies AST-TSA=0\tag3$$
where $\alpha_0I+\alpha_1S+...\alpha_nS^n=A$
but it is 0 so (3) holds trivially.
So, I cannot conclude anything about scalars $\alpha_i$'s which I need.

Any hint ?

I found this exact question on stack exchange but the answer used trace which I don't want to use here as this is a transformation rather than matrix.So, please some other insights would be helpful

Comment: $ST-TS=I$ is not possible if $V$ is finite dimensional (by a trace argument). But $V$ infinite dimensional implies $L(V)$ infinite dimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: define the linear operator $\Phi(A) = AT - TA$ on $L(V)$. Note that, on the polynomials of $S$, it works a little like differentiation. Think about how you might prove $\{1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^n\}$ are linearly independent polynomial functions using differentiation, and perhaps you might be able to adapt the proof.

Let me know if you want more guidance.

Comment: That was very helpful ^_^. I operated $\phi$ on my equation (2) n times to get $\alpha_n=0$ and that lead to zeroing of all the $\alpha$'s. Done.

Comment: @Chayan I'm glad!